# How to send mail depending on stdout?

Tags: bash, email

I need to send emails only when I have anything in stdout. Right now I send mails every 10 minutes configured in cron like this, even if the script returns nothing:

```
/root/script.sh|mail -s topic my@mail.com
```

How can I skip sending mails on null stdout?

Comment: dump output to a file. if file's empty, don't send the email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found even a better solution. Use the -E option for the mail command and it won't send e-mails if the body is empty. The manual for mail states the following.

```
-E      Do not send messages with an empty body.  This is useful for 
piping errors from cron(8) scripts.
```

So just like that.

```
/root/script.sh|mail -E -s topic my@mail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
message=$(/root/script.sh) && [[ ! -z "$message" ]] && mail -s topic my@mail.com  <<< "$message"
```

Meaning:

- store the output from the `script.sh` to an variable
- if the script.sh exits without error (exit status 0)
- check the content of the variable `message`
- and if it isn't empty
- send email

Comment: @RSahu: It's a Bash-ism, a 'here string'.  It's related to a here document, but uses a single string as the input.